# Await Promise.race(...)

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Как правильно использовать `await` с `Promise.race`? 
Пример:

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two');
});

async() => {
  let a = await Promise.race([p1, p2]);
  console.log(a);
}
```

Ничего не выводит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы объявляете, но не вызываете асинхронную функцию.

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one'); 
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two'); 
});

(async () => {
    let a = await Promise.race([p1,p2]);
    console.log(a);
    return a;
})().then(res => console.info('Result: ', res))
```

Comment: Спасибо, подвел компилятор, реагировал на reject(нет в примере) будто функция вызывалась